# How to fix label position inside Manipulate?

Tags: functions, manipulate

I'm trying to make this manipulation. 
Initially, I use `Text` to add `Happy Wedding`. However, the function doesn't allow me to format the font, color, etc. So I changed it and used `PlotLabel`. 
The problem is that the label position is moving with time. 
How can I fix its position on the top?

```
Manipulate[
 If[n =!= nold, vHues = Table[rhue[0.2, -0.15], {n}]; 
  mPositions = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {n, 2}]; 
  vSizes = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n}]; nold = n]; 
   Graphics[{Thickness[t], 
   Table[{vHues[[i]], hea[mPositions[[i]]*s, vSizes[[i]]^e]}, {i, n}]},
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style["Happy Wedding", 40, Hue[0.5/6], FontFamily -> "Mistral", 
    Background -> White],
   ImageSize -> {350, 350}], {{s, 1, "separation"}, 0.1, 2, 
  ControlType -> Animator}, {{e, 0.5, "size variation"}, 0.05, 2, 
  ControlType -> Animator}, 
  {{n, 10, "number"}, 1, 20, 1, 
  ControlType -> Animator}, {{t, 0.001, "thickness"}, 0.00001, 0.03, 
  ControlType -> Animator}, TrackedSymbols -> True, 
 ControllerLinking -> True, 
  Initialization :> {nold = 10,
   hea[{x_, y_}, 
     s_] := {BezierCurve[{{0, 0}, {1, 1 + RandomReal[]*0.3}, {0.5, 
         1.3 + RandomReal[]*0.3}, {0, 1}}], 
      BezierCurve[{{0, 0}, {-1, 1}, {-0.5 - (Plus[RandomReal[]])*0.3, 
         1.3}, {0, 1}}]} /. 
          {(x1_)?NumericQ, (y1_)?NumericQ} -> {x, y} + s*{x1, y1}}]
```

Comment: "I use Text to add Happy Wedding. However, the function doesn't allow me to format the font, …" You can always use `Style`.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: I mean you can adjust font, etc. of `Text` with `Style`,  check document of `Style` for more information, an example can also be found in the Properties & Relations section of document of `Text`.

Comment: @xzczd okay I see but I just tried and the problem is that the text is moving.

Comment: add the option `PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}`?

Comment: @kglr that works. Thanks, should I delete this thread?

Comment: Btw, how does adding that help?

Comment: @kglr I just found out that it doesn't really work. The text is fixed but the heart moving is wrong now. I just want to fix the text and everything keeps the same

Comment: try `Labeled[Graphics[{Thickness[t], 
   Table[With[{i = i}, {vHues[[i]], 
      hea[mPositions[[i]]*s, vSizes[[i]]^e]}], {i, n}]}, 
  ImageSize -> {350, 350}], 
 Style["Happy Wedding", 40, Hue[0.5/6], FontFamily -> "Mistral", 
  Background -> White], Top]`?

Comment: BTW definition of `rhue` is missing.

Comment: @kglr yeah, it works now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `Graphics[...]` with

```
Labeled[Graphics[{Thickness[t], 
    Table[{vHues[[i]], hea[mPositions[[i]]*s, vSizes[[i]]^e]}, {i, n}]}, 
   ImageSize -> {350, 350}], 
 Style["Happy Wedding", 40, Hue[0.5/6], FontFamily -> "Mistral", Background -> White], 
 Top]
```